# Presenting a view in Swift with Objective-C code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I usually work with Obj-C but I have 2 .swift files that I have imported into my project, what I am looking to do is launch one of the files, from one of my Obj-C viewController files (which subsequently is attached to a xib)

```
-(IBAction)gotoCompass:(id)sender {
    
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    
}
```

That is the action I want to use, the .swift file names are

ContentView.swift & CompassHeading.swift
I would like to present one of them using the IBAction above, but currently it shows

```
'Use of undeclared identifier 'let'
```

I have imported the Bridging-Header file and the top of the .m file is

```
FirstViewController.m

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
```

Edit -

Here is the contents of ContentView.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Marker: Hashable {
    let degrees: Double
    let label: String

    init(degrees: Double, label: String = "") {
        self.degrees = degrees
        self.label = label
    }

    func degreeText() -> String {
        return String(format: "%.0f", self.degrees)
    }

    static func markers() -> [Marker] {
        return [
            Marker(degrees: 0, label: "N"),
            Marker(degrees: 30),
            Marker(degrees: 60),
            Marker(degrees: 90, label: "E"),
            Marker(degrees: 120),
            Marker(degrees: 150),
            Marker(degrees: 180, label: "S"),
            Marker(degrees: 210),
            Marker(degrees: 240),
            Marker(degrees: 270, label: "W"),
            Marker(degrees: 300),
            Marker(degrees: 330)
        ]
    }
}

struct CompassMarkerView: View {
    let marker: Marker
    let compassDegress: Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(marker.degreeText())
                .fontWeight(.light)
                .rotationEffect(self.textAngle())
            
            Capsule()
                .frame(width: self.capsuleWidth(),
                       height: self.capsuleHeight())
                .foregroundColor(self.capsuleColor())
            
            Text(marker.label)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .rotationEffect(self.textAngle())
                .padding(.bottom, 180)
        }.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: marker.degrees))
    }
    
    private func capsuleWidth() -> CGFloat {
        return self.marker.degrees == 0 ? 7 : 3
    }

    private func capsuleHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return self.marker.degrees == 0 ? 45 : 30
    }

    private func capsuleColor() -> Color {
        return self.marker.degrees == 0 ? .red : .gray
    }

    private func textAngle() -> Angle {
        return Angle(degrees: -self.compassDegress - self.marker.degrees)
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var compassHeading = CompassHeading()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Capsule()
                .frame(width: 5,
                       height: 50)

            ZStack {
                ForEach(Marker.markers(), id: \.self) { marker in
                    CompassMarkerView(marker: marker,
                                      compassDegress: self.compassHeading.degrees)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 300,
                   height: 300)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.compassHeading.degrees))
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Also there is a `CompassHeading.swift` file;

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreLocation

class CompassHeading: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var degrees: Double = .zero {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    
    override init() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        self.degrees = -1 * newHeading.magneticHeading
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt I have posted the swift code just now

Comment: OK cool, but your question still makes no sense. These files cannot do any useful work out of their actual context. There is no sense in which you can "present" either of them (neither is a UIView, and the first one contains no code that Objective-C can even see). Stick to Objective-C. What's the _real_ problem you are trying to solve? Why did you ever try to borrow these Swift files in the first place? If your goal is to build some sort of heading compass, build it, don't try to steal it from Swift.

Comment: @matt I was mainly just playing around trying to see if I could get the project (which is just a basic compass) to launch from an action on an existing .xib file, that was my endgame,  (with thanks to the original code from https://github.com/programmingwithswift/Compass).

Comment: Well, you can't.

Comment: @matt Thats fair, will stick to obj-c but thank you :)